# Как вставить gif в html через ссылку?

Tags: html, css, gif

Есть ссылка на гиф как вставить в html?
https://yesno.wtf/assets/no/13-755222c98795431aa2e7d453ab1e75a1.gif

Comment: `<img src="https://yesno.wtf/assets/no/13-755222c98795431aa2e7d453ab1e75a1.gif"/>`

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что  ссылка ненадежная, не советую переходить

Answer (score 1):

Как и любую другую картинку:

```
<img src="https://yesno.wtf/assets/no/13-755222c98795431aa2e7d453ab1e75a1.gif"/>
```